# Find features installed by a sharepoint solution

Tags: sharepoint

Can i find the list of the features which were installed by a shareopoint solution?

Answer (score 1):

Unzip the wsp. From the unzipped folder you should be able to get all the features that are deployed using this wsp.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to lsiting the features of an installed solution I think this will do the trick.  You can add an if block to filter it down to a specific solution name/id if you wish.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class EnumerationTests
    {
    [Test]
    public void EnumeratingSiteFeatures()
    {
        using (var site = new SPSite("http://localhost:50000"))
        {
            var features = site.WebApplication.Farm.FeatureDefinitions;
            var solutions = site.WebApplication.Farm.Solutions;
            foreach (SPFeatureDefinition feature in features)
            {
                var solution = solutions[feature.SolutionId];
                var featureName = feature.DisplayName;
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Solution:{1}\nFeature:{0}\n", featureName, solution != null ? solution.DisplayName ?? solution.Name : "Solution was null"));
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```